# I can't access a private route using firebase

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a private route to be accessed only when the firebase listener verifies that the user is logged in, but I cannot access this route the way I am doing.

```
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    let autenticado = false;

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        autenticado = true;
      } else {
        autenticado = false;
      }
    });

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          autenticado ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  };

  const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  export default Routes;
```

Comment: where are you initializing your firebase app?

Comment: on an external component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell where your code is going wrong without seeing other components. I do basically the same approach when I set up firebase auth and set up private routes. I bring my context into my `PrivateRoute` component like so:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "./Auth";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
    const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={routeProps =>
                !!currentUser ? (
                    <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to={"/admin/login"} />
                )
            }
        />
    );
};
```

My `Auth.js` file is where I create my context like so:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import app from "./base.js";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I initiate my firebase instance in a file called `base.js` that looks like so :

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE)
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID
});

export default app;
```

In your routes you would then add the `AuthProvider`

```
const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
       </AuthProvider>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  export default Routes;
```

Comment: what im noticing with this solution, is that if you refresh your app, the private route kicks you back to the login page because it takes a few moments for the currentUser to re register.  do you by chance have a solution regarding this

Answer (score 2):

Alvaro's solution is good, but Robert Terrell brought up a good point:

> if you refresh your app, the private route kicks you back to the login page because it takes a few moments for the currentUser to re register
> .

To fix this, id wait for the authcontext to load before displaying the site on line 24 in AuthContext.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {auth, firebase} from "../firebaseSetup";

type ContextProps = {
    user: firebase.User | null;
};

export const AuthContext = React.createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null as firebase.User | null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
        setUser(user);
        setLoading(false);
    });
    }, []);

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
     value={{user}}>
      {!loading && children}
   </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```